# Refresh Service List of a paired Bluetooth device !

Tags: blackberry, jde

Is there any possibility to refresh the service list of a paired device in a programm? 
At the moment, i have to go to the bluetooth options and select the device properties of the bluetooth device and have to refresh the service list manually.

Is there any API that RIMM provides to do programmatically?

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using DiscoveryAgent.startInquiry()?  Or if you already have a RemoteDevice object for the device you're interested in, you could use DiscoveryAgent.searchServices()

http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/javax/bluetooth/DiscoveryAgent.html

Comment: Thanks for the info. DiscoveryAgent provides the searching for the services that is already cached in the local device during the pairing for the remote device. Once it's paired and if the remote device has been updated with the new service after some time by updating the firmware, then the device's new service needs to be registered. This can be done manually by using the option "Refesh Service List". But I want to do programmatically.

Comment: Are you sure you're not thinking about DiscoveryAgent.retrieveDevices() which only returns a cached list of known devices?  If you do a startInquiry() it should do an actual Bluetooth SDP query for local devices, which I assume would also update their service list records.

Comment: Thanks Marc. I will try and see whether that updates the service list records or not.